# PowerShell WMI function call with multiple variable

Tags: powershell, wmi

I want to call a WMI method which is taking one string as input , one integer as input and one integer as output.

Here is the Current Example:

```
$obj=Get-WmiObject -class "class1" -namespace "space1" $obj| Invoke-wmiMethod -name fun -ArgumentList $devUUID , $role , $status
```

Comment: You should provide a sample of what you're hoping to use/do and why it's not working. Additionally, always search and see if existing articles out there explain how to do things, for instance this first google result: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176860.aspx

Comment: $obj=Get-WmiObject -class "class1" -namespace "space1"
$obj| Invoke-wmiMethod -name fun -ArgumentList $devUUID , $role , $status

Comment: and there is no need of complter name because i am working on current host

Comment: $obj=Get-WmiObject -class "class1" -namespace "space1" 

$obj| Invoke-wmiMethod -name fun -ArgumentList $devUUID , $role , $status

Comment: You have an example, but it isn't clear what this is or how it relates.  Is it sample code you found somewhere?  If this what you're trying to use and it isn't giving you what you want?  If so, what result do you want, what does this code give you, and how is the result not satisfactory?

Answer (score 2):

What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

A simple Get-WMIObject and a couple of Read-Hosts should do what you need it to:

```
$className = Read-Host "Enter Class Name"
$computerName = Read-Host "Enter Computer Name"
if ([string]::IsNullOrWhitespace($computerName)) {
    $computerName = "."
}

Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computerName -Class $className
```

Bolt in a bit of extra error checking so that you aren't trying to check an invalid class name etc and you should be good to go. Example below:
[image]

---

You can also contatenate inside a command strings like so:

```
Get-WMIObject -Class ($string1 + "32" + "_" + $string2) -ComputerName "."
```

(in this case, $string1 contains "WIN" and $string2 contains "BIOS")

Things in brackets are processed before it's parent command.  You can even go deeper and do brackets within brackets.. PowerShell will start at the deepest level and work it's way out until it hits the parent command and then execute the fully computed strings.

Comment: you are not getting mi actual problem

Comment: i have problem in passing multiple input arguments but you have not discuss about this

Comment: What is the actual problem? Supply an example

Comment: [string]$UUID="mpx.msbha0:C2:T0:L0"
[int]$role=0
$wmiConnection=[WMICLASS]"root\wmi:myclass"
$methodParameter=$wmiConnection.psbase.getmethodsparameter("Myfunction")

Comment: ' [string]$UUID="mpx.msbha0:C2:T0:L0" '
' [int]$role=0 '
' $wmiConnection=[WMICLASS]"root\wmi:myclass" '
' $methodParameter=$wmiConnection.psbase.getmethodsparameter("Myfunction") '
' $methodParameter.UUID=$UUID '
' $methodParameter.role=$role '
'$wmiconnection.psbase.invokeMethod("Myfunction",$methodParameter,$null)'

I am getting 
' Exception calling InvokeMethod with 3 arguments: "Invalid method parameter"

Comment: Edit the examples in your opening posts with correct formats please, this is not very readable